# How to write to a file and, while the file is still being written, read and parse its contents using a shell script?

Tags: shell, redhat, scripting, files, redirection

I'm actually trying to write a shell script that logs the output of a command to a file, but since the command takes a long time to complete (about 15 minutes), I would like to start parsing the output of the command (content of the file) before the command is completed, so I can send messages to the standard output (the user), like:

```
10% complete
45% complete
```

and so on.

## Program steps

1. Redirect the command to a file: $(command) > $FILE
2. Start reading and parsing the output ($FILE) before the command is finished.

I thought of using parallel programming, but I havent't got the hang of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've actually solved the problem using `tail` and the Stack Overflow question *[Ending tail -f started in a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041437)*.

```
# Solution
($(command) > ${FILE}) &
tail -f --pid=$! ${FILE} | while read line
do
      echo $line
      # Can parse each line output here
      # Example: send errors to log file
      if echo $line | grep -qi "error"
      then
            echo $line >> ${LOG}
      fi
done
```

Thank you all for the help.

Comment: You probably don't want the dollar sign at the beginning of the line you're backgrounding.

Comment: Edited to do exactly that (I had the dollar sign at the wrong place). Thank you for the spotting it.

Answer (score 0):

Use tail and pipe that into your parser.

Answer (score 0):

tail -f  will *follow* the file as it being created.

try it with a log file.

tail -f /var/log/messages for example .

you'll see log file outputted to console as they appear in the log.

Answer (score 0):

Pipes, Tee, and Tail (tee being at the heart of the question as it duplicated standard output.  If sed were the file you were using to parse the data, an example would be:

```
kbrandt@k$ a=0; while [[ a -lt 10 ]]; do
> echo foo; a=$(( $a + 1));
> done | tee -a unprocessed | sed 's/foo/bar/' > processed
kbrandt@kbrandt$ cat unprocessed 
foo
foo
foo
...
kbrandt@kbrandt$ cat processed 
bar
bar
...
```

You can then run it as a job and tail processed, or just `tail -f processed` in another window.